# How to apply new foreground and background colors to verb?

Tags: color, verbatim

I want to change style of verb environment of my latex.

- Want a light gray background with red text.
- I tried using `newverbs` package I'm able to change `textcolor` or `backgroundcolor` but it's failing to use both once.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{newverbs}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\renewenvironment{verbatim}
{\semiverbatim\colorbox{gray!20}}
{\endsemiverbatim}
\renewcommand{\verb}{\collectverb{\colorbox{gray!20}}}

\colorbox{gray!20}{{\color{red}What I want}}


\verb|What I have|


\end{document}
```

- Above is the working example with only foreground changed.
- Below is the code I'm using for both.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{newverbs}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\renewenvironment{verbatim}
{\semiverbatim\colorbox{gray!20}\color{red}}
{\endsemiverbatim}
\renewcommand{\verb}{\collectverb{\colorbox{gray!20}\color{red}}}

\colorbox{gray!20}{{\color{red}What I want}}


\verb|What I have|


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You code does not work, because it would use `\color` as contents argument of `\colorbox`. You could define a new command:

```
\newcommand{\colorboxwithcontentcolor}[3]{\colorbox{#1}{\color{#2}#3}}
```

and use

```
\renewcommand{\verb}{\collectverb{\colorboxwithcontentcolor{gray!20}{red}}}
```

but easier would be to move `\color{red}` in front of `\colorbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{newverbs}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\verb}{\collectverb{\color{red}\colorbox{gray!20}}}

\colorbox{gray!20}{{\color{red}What I want}}


This is, \verb|what I have| and want.


\end{document}
```

[image]